# Permission Denied in Sublimetext3 unix

Tags: unix, sublimetext3, text-editor

I downloaded Sublimetext3, and tried saving a file and received "Error: Permission denied". I tried changing the Sharing and Permissions access and continue to receive the same error.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: try fixing your config using chwon `cd ~/.config; chown <username>:<username> sublime-text-3`

Comment: @ariestiyansyah actually, it would be `chown -R <username>:<username> sublime-text-3`. You need the `-R` "recursive" option or only the directory itself will be changed, not any of the enclosed files.

Comment: @Sara what user are you running Sublime as, and what file are you trying to edit? Did you previously run Sublime as root?

Comment: @mattdmo I'm using lord fresh as the user and I'm trying to edit sublime. I installed it using lord fresh. No I have not run Sublime as root